# Child processes cleanup after termination

Tags: go

I want to run another binary from go app with something like:

```
cmd := exec.Command("another_app_binary", "-config", "config.conf")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()
```

When I kill the parent process(code above), child process(another_app_binary) becomes orphan. What options do I have to cleanup child processes after parent exits/TERMINATES? It has to be somewhat platform nutural because I plan to run it on win/linux.

Comment: what about `cmd.Process.Kill()`

Comment: How do parent & child processes connect to your app / another_app_binary? Which one is which? Are you talking about killing another_app_binary's child processes? Please provide more information in the question.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [os/signal](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) package to listen for the kill signal in your current process.

```
import (
    "os/exec"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
)

// ...

cmd := exec.Command("another_app_binary", "-config", "config.conf")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()

c := make(chan os.Signal, 2)
signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)
go func() {
    <-c
    // cleanup
    cmd.Process.Kill()
    os.Exit(1)
}()

// ...
```